# Schoolgirl communicates with crab aliens by clicking her fingers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story I read in the '90s, in a collection that was not new.

A school teacher was told a ridiculous story by an apparently slow student. The teacher seemed to have some reason to take it at least partly seriously.

A bullet-sized spacecraft crashed through the roof into the student's attic, leaving a hole in a tile. It contained a number of dot-sized aliens that stayed in the attic and grew into giant crabs over the course of a few days or weeks. They communicated by clicking their claws, and the student quickly learned their language, clicking her fingers to converse with them. They were friendly, or at least didn't invade the earth.

Eventually they decided to leave. They left their giant crab bodies and piled back into the tiny ship, which launched through the roof with a sound like a gunshot.  I think the crab bodies disappeared so the only evidence was a pair of small holes (entry and exit) in the roof.

Comment: This is likely to be "The House Crab Project" by David Campton, published in [Armada Sci-fi 3](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?265680). I read at least 2 of Armada's _Sci-fi n_ series, and the title listing of 3 looks familiar - but I haven't yet found enough detail on any of the stories to confirm.